# How do I set "MONTHNAME()" function as column default in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, default, default-value

Actually **I need current month name as lowercase string** as default value in one of the table column;
DB table may look like Like:

```
name : john
joined : january
```

When I try to use mysql function `LOWER( MONTHNAME( NOW() ) )` as defailt value this gives me error. 
Btw I'm not interested in creating triggers.

any magic queries to do that?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Currently I'm using MySQL 5.7.*, by the accepted answer I knew that I can't do it, but be sure to post an answer if you've any trick.

Comment: Btw I can do it exactly stated in the question in MariaDB 10.3 (which still using MySQL 5.7.*), Adding this comment to help someone who's using MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> With one exception, enclose expression default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal constant default values.

So, the following should work:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    month_name VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT (LOWER(MONTHNAME(NOW())))
    ...
)
```

As @Madhur has pointed out, using an expression as a default will only work from MySQL 8 onwards.

Comment: I think a caveat needs to be added that it will work only from version **8.0.13** and onwards.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but unfortunately I'm working with 5.7.*, is there any solution for that?

Comment: I think you would need to use a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

If you use MySQL 8.0 or later, then the answers provided by @TimBiegeleisen and @fa06 should solve the problem. In otherwise

> ... the default value specified in a DEFAULT clause must be a literal constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

*See details in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html).*

So, for previous versions you need to find another way. For example, you could define a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) that sets default value for the column if the value is not specified:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  joined  VARCHAR(12)
);

CREATE TRIGGER defaultMonth
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.joined = IFNULL(NEW.joined, LOWER(MONTHNAME(NOW())));
```

See also [live example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pF1UqGWEQJzTdXbKGn3LVP/0) for the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
CREATE TABLE orderdata (

    order_date DATE
  , order_month VARCHAR(50) AS (lower(MONTHNAME(order_date))) 

);
```